# Write a zip file to disk after decrypting it with Ruby GPGME

Tags: ruby, pgp

I've been able to PGP decrypt a zip file using Ruby GPGME but I'm unclear how to correctly write it to disk. Here's what I have:

```
crypto = GPGME::Crypto.new
result = crypto.decrypt(File.open('myfile.zip.pgp'))
#Now what?
```

I tried this:

```
File.open('myfile.zip', 'wb' ) do |output|
  output.write [result.read].pack("B*")
end
```

But the resulting file can't be unzipped. Result is type GPGME::Data and result.read returns a String, but I'm not sure if I'm supposed to be doing that or not. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Figured it out right after I posted this: crypto.decrypt(File.open(path), output: File.open(destination_path, 'wb'))

Answer (score 0):

Piece of cake:

```
crypto = GPGME::Crypto.new
crypto.decrypt(File.open(path), output: File.open(destination_path, 'wb'))
```